# Laravel 5 getparentsTree

Tags: laravel-5

Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: C:\php\laravellp\resources\views\admin\product_edit.blade.php)

C:\php\laravellp\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController inner title line error i think

public static function getParentsTree($category,$title)

```
{

    if ($category->parent_id == 0)

    {

        return $title;

    }

    $parent = Category::find($category->parent_id);

    ***$title = $parent->title. ' > ' . $title;***


    return CategoryController::getParentsTree($parent,$title);

}
```

Comment: `find` can return `null` you should check this query

Answer (score 0):

[catagories table ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVjrS.jpg)

database error. if you have already entered data in the category table in your database. If the product_id remains automatically assigned, it will be the value of product_id. The reason for the error here is that the product_id are confusing the database. I got rid of the error by setting the product_id in the table to 0.